# google analytics tracking social urls

Tags: google-analytics

hello guys I am new at google analytics and I want to integrate a functionality. In my website I am giving credit to user on each post share on social site like fb or twitter etc ,now I want to track those shared url if 3 peoples click on that shared url on social site with different ip then I want to give 3 credits to the person who has shared that post , any I think it can be done by google analytics so any one have suggestion how to achieve this type of functionality
thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is not the right tool for this because it is not easy to get data out to know how many credits you should give.

You should use a specific url tracker for this, which would update your credits counter in real time.